# How to limit form submition per time after submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I'm googling how to limit user submission per time. I have a form that user's submit their info constantly. It works fine, but how can I limit a user to submit the form every other day, for example if the user submit today and he tries to submit form after a few hours he can't until 24 hours are through.

```
 // attempt insert query execution

$sql = "INSERT INTO request (fname, lname, amount, cedula,user_id, category, points,comments ) VALUES ('$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[amount]','$_POST[cedula]','$user_id' ,'$user_cat','$points','$_POST[comments]' )";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql )){


    header("Location: http://www.loan2center.com/users/submitthankyou.php");
    echo "Records added successfully.";
}
else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
```

this is the post i was thinking if i declare $DATE = date("Y/m/d"); then modify if(mysqli_query($link, $sql && $date <= 24000)){///   so this way it can limit it, but i dont know if it will work or which is the best aproach for this

Comment: If you use a database, you can add a column that keeps the time of the last request, and then in the form, you can check if this time is older than 1 day.

Comment: the database table request gather name, last-name, comments, req requestid and date, so where do i validate this code, will it be after the post value are clear, after the form is submitted i use header to redirect, so basically before header i will have to do something like . $date = date from databa,      if ($date somecode >24000); for submitted; else { echo " plase wait xxxxxxxxx"}

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your implementation on the backend, but logically you want to allow the user to submit the form and then on your server, check the current time compared with the timestamp of their last entry. If the difference is less than 24 hours then return a 400 bad request and handle that in the client.

Comment: on the form post method                               if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){  at this point it got all the info including id, date etc, here i believe is where the condition must go for 24 hours limit submission, but i dont know exactly how to develop the syntaxes

Comment: Update your question with more code if you would like more specific help. But regardless this is a condition you want after the user has submitted the form on the server rather than on the client.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the user has requested earlier than 24 hours, before you load the form for the requests. Also, you should add a column of type DATETIME (named latest_request in the code below) for the latest request's time and date, in the requests table of your database.

In your php for the request form:

```
<?php
$user = --- ; // Give the $user variable the id of the current user.
$sql = "SELECT user_id, latest_request FROM requests WHERE user_id='$user'"

$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();
$can_request = 0; // Will be 0 if user has requested within 24 hours, 1 otherwise

if ($result['latest_request']!='')
{
    $cur_datetime = new DateTime('now');
    $latest_request = new DateTime($result['latest_request']);
    $diff = $cur_datetime->diff($latest_request);
    $diff_in_days = intval($diff->format('%d'));
    if ($diff_in_days > 0)
        $can_request = 1;
}

if ($can_request)
{
    ?>
    // Put here your Request form
    <?php
}
else
{
    echo "Sorry, you can only request one day after your last request.";
}
?>
```

In your php for after request form is submitted:

```
date_default_timezone_set("/* Put here your continent/city, eg Europe/London */");
$latest_request = (string)date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$sql = "INSERT INTO requests (fname, lname, amount, cedula,user_id, category, points,comments, latest_request) VALUES ('$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[amount]','$_POST[cedula]','$user_id' ,'$user_cat','$points','$_POST[comments]' )";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql ))
{
    header("Location: http://www.loan2center.com/users/submitthankyou.php");
    echo "Records added successfully.";
}
else
{
    echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Here you can find a list for timezones supported by php: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php.

I hope I helped you with your problem. Please let me know if somthing goes wrong, or if you want something more. Other helpful links:

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

Comment: i did exactly as you told me, but i getting an error page isn’t working. and i <?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);?>        but cant get to see the error, i viewed everything over but cant seems to find an error

Comment: I need you to tell me how you have organized your work. Are these all in one .php file? Have you set the database properly? Which page do you load when you get the error? What does the error tell you (perhaps send me a screenshot)?

Comment: yes i added everything on the same page where the HTML for is located ther is [my_code](http://loan2center.com/xxxxx.html), I did an echo to $users to make sure it works, and everyting is fine, but when i add the rest of code tha is when i get HTTP ERROR 500 on the page,

Comment: HTTP ERROR 500 is a general server error, and I can't understand what causes it. Perhaps the communication with your database doesn't work. More info: (http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html). DON'T WORRY! I will post on a new answer the full code that I tested and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well the most simple approach would be to store datetime in the table when you are storing the form data for a specific user, so just before inserting a new record you need to check if there has been an entry by the same userid within past 24 hours then gracefully show him/her the message, else go ahead and submit the form normally.

Comment: i had a date record already in my database named date, its a hidden field, i tried using that but still got blank page , i believe it can be a syntax error, fetch the date isn't the problem creating the php scrip to limit is what im struggling with

Comment: well in php code you can do something like this to calculate the difference in days:    $date_1 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$date_2 = DB datetime;
$days_diff = $date_2->diff($date_1)->format("%a");

This will give you difference in days

Comment: using that then i can say if $days_diff > 24, { ?>
    // Put here your Request form
    <?php    else { echo }. im seeing 2 option which tells me that it can be done, guess i got a lot more to learn, i really appreciate this help

Comment: In your case it should be $days_diff > 1 not $days_diff > 24 coz 24 is hours

Comment: ok thanks i will give it try im trying to fetch $date_2 right now, you make it look so simple

Answer (score 0):

Herre is the complete code, which works fine for me:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test"); // Complete this with your database data.
mysqli_set_charset ( $mysqli , "utf8" );

$user = 1 ; // Give the $user variable the id of the current user.

if (!isset($_POST["submit"]))
{

    $sql = "SELECT user_id, latest_request FROM requests WHERE user_id='$user' ORDER BY latest_request DESC";

    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
    echo $mysqli->error; // Use this to see if there is an error in your SQL query.
    $result = $query->fetch_assoc();
    $can_request = 0; // Will be 0 if user has requested within 24 hours, 1 otherwise

    if ($result['latest_request']!='')
    {
        $cur_datetime = new DateTime('now');
        $latest_request = new DateTime($result['latest_request']);
        $diff = $cur_datetime->diff($latest_request);
        $diff_in_days = intval($diff->format('%d'));
        if ($diff_in_days > 0)
            $can_request = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $can_request = 1;
    }

    if ($can_request)
    {
        ?>

        <form action="" method="post">
        <input name="fname" type="text"><br><br>
        // Add here all the other inputs you want<br><br>
        <input name="submit" type="submit">
        </form>

        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Sorry, you can only request one day after your last request.<br>";
        echo "You requested at: ".$latest_request->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
}
else
{
    date_default_timezone_set("/* Put here your continent/city, eg Europe/London */");
    $cur_datetime = (string)date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    // In the code below, add all the data you want to save in the table (fname, lname, amount, cedula, category, points, comments)
    $sql = "INSERT INTO requests (user_id, latest_request) VALUES ('$user','$cur_datetime')";

    $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ($mysqli->error == "")
    {
        echo "OK";
        header("Location: http://www.loan2center.com/users/submitthankyou.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo $mysqli->error;
    }
}
?>
```

Does the error still appear? Please let me know!

Comment: ok , the diferrence that i see is that you did everything on one same page, i have my form on 1 page and post(data base connection on another) that works fine for me cause i have validations on both pages, i replaced latest_request for date, because  i had date on the table already for each submit along with user id, keeping on 2 different pages it seems that is the issue, so i will have to find a way to modify

Comment: Do you include the php for database connection in the other php and use the same variables (eg $mysqli) ? Because I can't see any `include('database.php')` in the image you gave me.

Comment: here is all [my-code](loan2center.com/xxxxx.html) sorry but for now this is the only way i can upload img, hope you can understand, it works fine for me until now that i need to limit submit by time, 2 question when i get this working if i want to increase period from 24hours to maybe 48 how or were i change to get this done

Comment: Just replace the if statement `if ($diff_in_days > 0)` with `if ($diff_in_days > 1)`. If you want to get difference in hours replace `$diff_in_days = intval($diff->format('%d'));        if ($diff_in_days > 0)` with `$diff_in_hours = intval($diff->format('%h'));        if ($diff_in_hours > 48)`.

Comment: i'm still struggling trying to declare $date_2  //// i got to fetch it but when i tried to delcare $date_2 =  $info['date']  ;  i get blank value

Comment: First of all, in your code inside the sql query with select write this: `SELECT * FROM requests WHERE user_id='$user' ORDER BY date DESC";`, I mean replace latest_request before DESC with date, because you've renamed it and put * after select to get all the columns. Now, supposing you use $info['date'] to get that date from the table (meaning $result['latest_request'] in my code), the fact that you get blank means that the sql didn't return anything or that in the row it found, the column date was empty. Try to echo $info['fname'] for example to determine what's wrong and tell me.

Comment: <?php
$data = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM request WHERE user_id= $user_id ORDER BY latest_request DESC LIMIT 1")  or die(mysql_error());
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 {
  echo "<td>" .$info['date']. "</td>" ; 
 }
 
?>    is what i have and it works  but now i need to declare the output as a value

Comment: Again, you didn't change the `latest_request` to `date` just before the DESC LIMIT 1 in sql query.

Comment: sorry i did changed it, the fecth works i got the value, but when i want to declare the echo as a value is when i get a blank value

Comment: First of all, use mysqli instead of mysql because mysql was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Did you try to echo another column? Because perhaps in your database the date column is not set. Have you manually added rows in the database, to test this?Check this and tell me.

Comment: However, this code works for me: `$data = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM requests WHERE user_id= $user_id ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error()); while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { echo "<td>" .$info['date']. "</td>" ; } `. It echos the right date.

Comment: i finally got to manage date difference and get echo and it works fine but for some reason when i do if ($dteDiff < 3 ) {?>  ///my form >?php {else echo "xxxxxxxxxxx"; }  it doesn't work, example the date diff is 5 , so by using <3 to display from should work, but it doesn't instead it doesn't display the form, what i need is if d submitted date is greater  than 3 days access form, less that 3 do not access form

Answer (score 0):

Background:
I made a hidden form to automatically store user data at a specific time, however, due to the time I entered it submitted the form every second for every user for a minute, thus resulting in 60 entries per user per minute.

---

To fix this I used part of the code provided by @Thanasis1101. I used the normal method of posting a record, but before running the `INSERT INTO table (columns) VALUES (record_values)` script I added the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_stats WHERE id='$id' ORDER BY date DESC";

        $query = $conn->query($sql);
        $result = $query->fetch_assoc();
        $can_request = 0; // Will be 0 if user has requested within 24 hours, 1 otherwise

        if ($result['date'] !=''){
            $cur_datetime = new DateTime('now');
            $date = new DateTime($result['date']);
            $diff = $cur_datetime->diff($date);
            $diff_in_hours = intval($diff->format('%h'));
            if ($diff_in_hours > 12)
                $can_request = 1;
        }
        else {
            $can_request = 1;
        }

        if ($can_request){
```

This prevented the form from being submitted at all for 12 hours after the last submission. HOWEVER, I must add for some reason in the line `if ($result['date'] !=''){` the first time a user submits data it adds the record but throws out an error (PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null) due to the fact that my database is set up to add the date stamp automatically not get it from the form. If you add it via a form it should not give you the error.

Answer (score -1):

i was able to solve my request.
basically i needed to limit access to request form by periods. Example form was submitted today,user will not be able to access it until 3 days after and also when a new user was created provide access to request form . this is my code

```
<?php
 // will declare variable 
 $current_now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$last_request = $request_last_date->req_date; // last submitted date on data base(hidden field within the form)
$dtestart = new DateTime($current_now);
$dteEnd = new DateTime($last_request);
$dteDiff  = $dteEnd ->diff($dtestart); 
 $access = 224;
if ($dteDiff->format('%d%h%') > $access )

    {echo "u can  access  now";//>? form <?php

    }elseif ($dteDiff->format('%d%h%') == 00 )
    {
    echo "if new user also access";//>? form <?php
    }
            else {

                echo " u wait , no access";
            }
                >?
```

it was made this way because for new user that had not submit any form is last_request date is "0" and the code was set for last date above 3 to have access.

date difference i use days and hours as 1 example 224= 3days exactly 2days and 24 hours and that's why$access=224.

hope it helps someone in the future if so, please thumbs up will appreciate